# Fixed Header Overlaying Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, fixed

I have a fixed header implemented in my CSS but for some reason, it's overlaying the browser's scroll bar. I'm not sure why it's doing this but it seems like everything else I change doesn't help. Any idea?

[image: Scrollbar is covered by the fixed header]

- **http://jsfiddle.net/HjBhW/**

**HTML:**

> ```
> <header class="clearfix">
>   test
> </header>
>
> <div id="wrapper">
>   <div id="content">
>       Content
>   </div><!-- end #content --> 
> </div><!-- end #wrapper -->
>
> <div id="footer">
>           <center>footer</center>
> </div>
> ```

**CSS:**

> ```
> <style type="text/css">
> * {
>   margin:0;               
>   padding:0;              
> }
> html, body {
>   height:100%;            
>
>   overflow:auto;      
>   background:#2f3742;
>   color: #B8C2CB;
> }
> #wrapper {
>   min-height:100%;    
>   width:600px;        
>   margin: -30px auto;     
>   background:#47535e;
>   border: 1px solid #3D4857;
>   border-bottom: 0;
>
> }
> * html #wrapper { 
>   height:100%;        
> }
> #content {
>   margin-top: 100px;
>   padding: 5px;
> }
> header {
>   height: 70px;
>   padding: 22px 25px;
>   background: #18232f;
>   text-align: center; 
>   position: absolute !important;
>   width: 100%;
>   z-index: 1;
>   top:0;
>   left:0; 
> }
> #footer {
>   height:30px;
>   width:600px; 
>   margin: 25px auto 0;
>   background:#2F3742;
>   border: 1px solid #3D4857;
>   border-top: 1px solid #2F3A4A;
> }
> </style>
> ```

Comment: Chrome and Firefox (latest)

Comment: I can't replicate it in FF30.0 using your fiddle.

Comment: Doesn't occur within the jdfiddle frame... try putting the same code in an index.html and launch it directly from there.

Comment: Any reason you want to scroll within the Body itself rather than let the Browser scroll for you? I'm referring to your CSS on html and body of overflow: auto;

Comment: Nope. It seems to be my only solution to have a fixed header along with a body that touches the end of the footer where the footer is ALSO fixed and touches the bottom of the window. (I know... I'm needy :-P)

Comment: Setting body {overflow: auto;} is certainly is not your only solution to achieving a fixed header and footer. I might go knock up a fiddle for you.

Comment: Much appreciated if you would!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:** the scrollbar is on your body, so add  a margin-top to your body and your scrollbar (along with the rest of the top of your content will reappear).

```
body {
    margin-top:110px;
}
```

**Fixed JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9CkNC/1/

**Long Answer:** Note that other problems arise after this fix is made. There are a bunch of little tweaks that might be useful to make in your CSS, and I've added a bunch of comments that should help a little in the JSFiddle. Also, making a static header bar is a very common technique in the web design world, so there are a lot of great blog posts about it. I would do some snooping to see how other people have done it.

This is a great one to start with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3I2Uh-D-lzI

### How I do it:

- If I want a fixed header *and* footer, I usually go with something like this: http://jsbin.com/malub/1/edit?html,css,output
- If I want only a fixed header, I do something like this: http://jsbin.com/qewak/1/edit?html,css,output
- If I want a fixed header and footer and I still want the scrollbar to be the height of the window, I'll do this: http://jsbin.com/zitiqa/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Oh it looks like I linked the wrong JSFiddle. Did you try it yourself or look at the other parts of my answer?

Comment: Yes. I have attempted to recreate the one with the fixed header and footer but I did not like how the scrollbar only appeared within the body. It looks like an iframe which is what I'm not aiming for. I was looking forward to having the scrollbar in the whole window with the header and footer fixed within.

Comment: This is fantastic but the same issue from the other solution occurs where the background (let's say a gradient) set to the body does not dynamically cover: http://i.imgur.com/GyBMBY1.png

Comment: Don't set a background on the body. Set it on `<main>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I already have another background set for <main> and was looking forward to use a dynamic gradient background for <body>. I'm so close to what I need!

Comment: You actually can set multiple backgrounds on a single element. Also, if you need to, you can probably fix the body with some more styling. Or use the `before` or `after` pseudo elements on `main`. Or add a wrapper.

Comment: What I've done is made my <main> element to a width of 600px with its own gradient background. For the past hour now, I've been trying to figure out how to get a dynamic background for everything else behind it that covers the empty space outside <main>. Doesn't have to cover the backgrounds of the header and footer. Hmmm

Comment: I think I got it... I basically set a <div> with the gradient background within <body></body> and it seems to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I would post a new SE question with what you've done thus far and a very specific description of what you want to see. Make sure to avoid an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 3):

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HjBhW/9/)

Three things i observe in your code:

> You have giving padding in your header with 100% width
>
> Giving body `overflow:auto`
>
> Giving `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed` for fixing the header

CSS WILL BE:

```
* {
    margin:0;               /* zero out margin */
    padding:0;              /* zero out padding */
}
html, body {
    height:100%;            /* gives layout 100% height */
    background:#2f3742;
    color: #B8C2CB;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;        /* gives layout 100% height */
    width:600px;            /* centered div must be given a width */
    margin: -30px auto;             /* centers #wrapper */
    background:#47535e;
    border: 1px solid #3D4857;
    border-bottom: 0;
    
}
* html #wrapper { 
    height:100%;            /* IE6 treats height as min-height */
}
#content {
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
}
p {
    font-size:1.8em;
    text-align:center;
    padding:30px 0 30px;    /* bottom padding clears the #footer */
}
#header {
    height:70px;
    width:600px;            /* centered div must be given a width */
/*  margin: 0 auto -70px; */    /* -80px sucks it back in & auto centers it */
    background-color:#18232f;
    /* background-color:#2F3742; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2F3A4A;
}

header {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #18232f;
  text-align: center; 
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.inner-header { padding:20px 25px; }

#footer {
    height:30px;
    width:600px;                /* centered div must be given a width */
    margin: 25px auto 0;            /* -80px sucks it back in & auto centers it */
    background:#2F3742;
    /* bottom: 0; */
    border: 1px solid #3D4857;
    border-top: 1px solid #2F3A4A;
}
```

HTML :

```
<header class="clearfix">
    <div class="inner-header">
  test
    </div>
</header>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
      Content
  </div><!-- end #content --> 
</div><!-- end #wrapper -->

<div id="footer">
          <center>footer</center>
</div>
```

Comment: You beat me to it, happy to gather requirements for you :-)

Comment: Its my pleasure always :) :P

Comment: The header is not fixed though... if I populate the #content body vertically and scroll, the header is no longer on top. Footer appears to stretch further than the body.

Comment: @theflarenet please check my updated fiddle in my answer

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you. However I'm encountering one more problem: http://i.imgur.com/GyBMBY1.png

Comment: I've tried solving it on my own and I'm unable to figure it out.